# Problem with import Google Cloud Speech-to-Text recognition

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I'm trying to

```
from google.cloud import speech
```

but have error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
  from google.cloud import speech
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/speech.py", line 19, in <module>
  from google.cloud.speech_v1 import SpeechClient
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/speech_v1/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
  from google.cloud.speech_v1.gapic import speech_client
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/speech_v1/gapic/speech_client.py", line 26, in <module>
import google.api_core.operation
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/operation.py", line 45, in <module>
  from google.longrunning import operations_pb2
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/longrunning/operations_pb2.py", line 23, in <module>
  from google.longrunning.operations_grpc_pb2 import *
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/longrunning/operations_grpc_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
  from google.api import annotations_pb2 as google_dot_api_dot_annotations__pb2
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api/annotations_pb2.py", line 15, in <module>
  from google.api import http_pb2 as google_dot_api_dot_http__pb2
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api/http_pb2.py", line 22, in <module>
serialized_pb=_b('\n\x15google/api/http.proto\x12\ngoogle.api\"T\n\x04Http\x12#\n\x05rules\x18\x01 \x03(\x0b\x32\x14.google.api.HttpRule
                  \x12\'\n\x1f\x66ully_decode_reserved_expansion\x18\x02 \x01(\x08\"\x81\x02\n\x08HttpRule\x12\x10\n\x08selector\x18\x01
                  \x01(\t\x12\r\n\x03get\x18\x02 \x01(\tH\x00\x12\r\n\x03put\x18\x03 \x01(\tH\x00
                  \x12\x0e\n\x04post\x18\x04 \x01(\tH\x00\x12\x10\n\x06\x64\x65lete\x18\x05 \x01(\tH\x00\x12\x0f\n\x05patch\x18\x06 \x01(\tH\x00\x12/\n\x06\x63ustom\x18\x08 \x01(\x0b\x32\x1d.google.api.CustomHttpPatternH\x00\x12\x0c\n\x04\x62ody\x18\x07 \x01(\t\x12\x15\n\rresponse_body\x18\x0c \x01(\t\x12\x31\n\x13\x61\x64\x64itional_bindings\x18\x0b \x03(\x0b\x32\x14.google.api.HttpRuleB\t\n\x07pattern\"/\n\x11\x43ustomHttpPattern\x12\x0c\n\x04kind\x18\x01 \x01(\t\x12\x0c\n\x04path\x18\x02 \x01(\tBj\n\x0e\x63om.google.apiB\tHttpProtoP\x01ZAgoogle.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api/annotations;annotations\xf8\x01\x01\xa2\x02\x04GAPIb\x06proto3')

TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialized_options'
```

Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, 
Inc, Google Cloud SDK 228.0.0, 
app-engine-python 1.9.80, 
bq 2.0.39, 
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.0.2, 
core 2018.12.07, 
gsutil 4.34,

Comment: Try: `pip install -U protobuf`

Comment: It works. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please run the below command

pip install -U protobuf

This will solve the problem.